# How to toggle the display of a division with onclick event with a button in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to display a corresponding `<div>` when the corresponding button is clicked. Basically I want to display `hey man!` and `hey woman!` when the corresponding button is clicked.
So, I have two such buttons:

```
<div className="row">
  <button className="btn col-6 bg-transparent col-12 col-sm-6" onclick={() => this.togglediv("showdiv1")}  >
    <img className="humanbody profile" src={malebody} />
  </button>
  <button className="btn col-6 bg-transparent col-12 col-sm-6" onclick={() => this.togglediv("showdiv2")}  >
    <img className="humanbody profile" src={femalebody} alt="" />
   </button>
</div>
```

Here the onclick events are handled using this code:

```
class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            showdiv1: false,
            showdiv2: false
        };
        this.togglediv = this.togglediv.bind(this);
    }

    togglediv(div_name) {
        switch (div_name) {
            case "showdiv1":
                this.setState({ showdiv1: !this.state.showdiv1 });
                break;
            case "showdiv2":
                this.setState({ showdiv2: !this.state.showdiv2 });
                break;
        }
    }

    render() {

        const { showdiv1, showdiv2 } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="container py-5">

                <div className="row">
                    <button className="btn col-6 bg-transparent col-12 col-sm-6" onclick={() => this.togglediv("showdiv1")}  >
                        <img className="humanbody profile" src={malebody} />
                    </button>
                    <button className="btn col-6 bg-transparent col-12 col-sm-6" onclick={() => this.togglediv("showdiv2")}  >
                        <img className="humanbody profile" src={femalebody} />
                    </button>
                </div>

                
                {/* Hidden div */}
                <div className="row">
                    {
                        showdiv1 && (
                            <div>
                                Hey man!
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                    {
                        showdiv2 && (
                            <div>
                                Hey woman!
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                </div>
                {/* Hidden div */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home;
```

The hidden divisions aren't appearing on the screen when the buttons are clicked.

Edit: I mistakenly wrote `onlcick` in place of `onClick` in the code which when corrected, is working fine.

Comment: why to hide `class=row` then?

Comment: you are not redisplaying the hidden `row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the event name `onClick` instead of `onclick`.

Another approach, just to use one state named `isShowMan`, then toggle it properly in case you just need one div is displayed at a time.

```
  toggleShowMan(isShow) {
    this.setState({ isShowMan: isShow });
  }
  ...................................
  <button className="btn col-6 bg-transparent col-12 col-sm-6"
  onClick={() => this.toggleShowHide(true)}>malebody </button>


  ..................Show/Hide propertly................
    <div className="row">
      {isShowMan && <div>Hey man!</div>}
      {!isShowMan && <div>Hey woman!</div>}
    </div>
```

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { isShowMan: true };
  }

  toggleShowMan(isShow) {
    this.setState({ isShowMan: isShow });
  }

  render() {
    const { isShowMan } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="container py-5">
        <div className="row">
          <button disabled={isShowMan}
            className="btn col-6 bg-transparent col-12 col-sm-6"
            onClick={() => this.toggleShowMan(true)}
          >malebody </button>
          <button disabled={!isShowMan}
            className="btn col-6 bg-transparent col-12 col-sm-6"
            onClick={() => this.toggleShowMan(false)}
          >
            femalebody
          </button>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          {isShowMan && <div>Hey man!</div>}
          {!isShowMan && <div>Hey woman!</div>}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @Kanchan Bharti Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Yeah, that `onClick` was the first issue in this code. And after using just `showman` in the state, my code is now able to show one div at a time, which I wanted.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome, I as guessed based on the UI/UX ^^!

Comment: I am also trying to convert the code such that only the corresponding word i.e. `man` and `woman` in this case, should be displayed without changing the whole div. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Also, while using just showman in state, it will render `hey woman` on the screen as default. How to solve that?

Comment: You can change this default state at here `this.state = { isShowMan: true};` from `true` to `false` as you wish :)

Comment: To avoid the complex question? You can create a new one, then tag me, I'll help you :)

Comment: when `isShowMan` is false which is by default, then it is rendering `hey woman`.

Comment: @KanchanBharti Pls, give me the link to your new question in more detailed requirements. I'll answer it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65991016/13037132 

kindly help me with this.

Comment: I see, Let me do it now.

Answer (score 2):

Working Example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mq3rcz?file=src%2FApp.js)

You are using `onclick` instead of `onClick` in `button`:

```
<div className="row">
    <button className="btn col-6 bg-transparent col-12 col-sm-6" onClick={() => this.togglediv("showdiv1")}  >
        <img className="humanbody profile" src={malebody} />
    </button>
    <button className="btn col-6 bg-transparent col-12 col-sm-6" onClick={() => this.togglediv("showdiv2")}  >
        <img className="humanbody profile" src={femalebody} />
    </button>
</div>
```

Full Working Sourcecode:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showdiv1: false,
      showdiv2: false
    };
    this.togglediv = this.togglediv.bind(this);
  }

  togglediv(div_name) {
    switch (div_name) {
      case "showdiv1":
        this.setState({ showdiv1: !this.state.showdiv1 });
        break;
      case "showdiv2":
        this.setState({ showdiv2: !this.state.showdiv2 });
        break;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { showdiv1, showdiv2 } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="container py-5">
        <div className="row">
          <button
            className="btn col-6 bg-transparent col-12 col-sm-6"
            onClick={() => this.togglediv("showdiv1")}
          >
            <img
              className="humanbody profile"
              src={"https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8vJf.jpg?s=328&g=1"}
            />
          </button>
          <button
            className="btn col-6 bg-transparent col-12 col-sm-6"
            onClick={() => this.togglediv("showdiv2")}
          >
            <img
              className="humanbody profile"
              src={"https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8vJf.jpg?s=328&g=1"}
            />
          </button>
        </div>

        {/* Hidden div */}
        <div className="row">
          {showdiv1 && <div>Hey man!</div>}
          {showdiv2 && <div>Hey woman!</div>}
        </div>
        {/* Hidden div */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

A more concise approach can be

```
const MALE = 'MALE'
const FEMALE = 'FEMALE'
export const Home =  () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(null)
  const isMale = visible === MALE
  const isFemale = visible === FEMALE

  (
            <div className="container py-5">

                <div className="row">
                    <button className="btn col-6 bg-transparent col-12 col-sm-6" onClick={() => setVisible(MALE)}  >
                        <img className="humanbody profile" src={malebody} />
                    </button>
                    <button className="btn col-6 bg-transparent col-12 col-sm-6" onClick={() => setVisible(FEMALE)}  >
                        <img className="humanbody profile" src={femalebody} />
                    </button>
                </div>

                
                {/* Hidden div */}
                <div className="row">
                    {
                        isMale && (
                            <div>
                                Hey man!
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                    {
                        isFemale && (
                            <div>
                                Hey woman!
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                </div>
                {/* Hidden div */}
            </div>
        )
  

}
```

Comment: Nice with using `functional component`. But one thing `onClick ` instead of `onclick`

Comment: @Phong thank you :) I copied the code from the question and I forgot to correct that typo