# How to change a text inside an element, corresponding to an onClick event in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am displaying two divisions corresponding, to two button's onClick event:

```
class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isShowaMale: false
        };
        this.toggleShowMale = this.toggleShowMale.bind(this);
    }

    toggleShowMale(show) {
        this.setState({ isShowaMale:show });
    }

    render() {

        const { isShowaMale } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="container py-5">

                <div className="row">
                    <button className="btn col-6 bg-transparent col-12 col-sm-6" onClick={() => this.toggleShowMale(true)}  >
                        <img className="humanbody profile" src={malebody} />
                    </button>
                    <button className="btn col-6 bg-transparent col-12 col-sm-6" onClick={() => this.toggleShowMale(false)}  >
                        <img className="humanbody profile" src={femalebody} alt="" />
                    </button>
                </div>

                
                {/* Hidden div */}
                <div className="row mx-auto">
                    {isShowaMale && (
                        <div className="mx-auto">
                            Hey man!
                        </div>
                    )}
                    {!isShowaMale && (
                        <div>
                            Hey woman!
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
                {/* Hidden div */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home;
```

But, can I just display one div and change just the word `man` and `woman` in the text `Hey ____`? And there is also a problem that, after reloading the web page, it always shows `Hey woman` due to `isShowaMale: false` being default state. How can I solve these?

Comment: `<div className="mx-auto">{ isShowaMale ? 'Hey man!' : 'Hey woman!' }</div>`

Comment: I am using 'Hey man!' as an example, I will be replacing those with two separate forms (which I haven't done yet), so, I will need some objects whose values will change according to the buttons clicked. And I will use those objects in place of texts like `man` and `woman`. Is it possible or I need to write two separate forms for this purpose?

Comment: The concept does not change: `<div className="mx-auto">{ isShowaMale ? <ManComponent /> : <WomanComponent /> }</div>`

Comment: Yeah okay, I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Can I just display one div and change just the word man and woman in
>    the text `Hey ____`

```
   <div className="row">
      {`Hey ${isShowMan? " man" : "woman"}!`} 
    </div>
```

> 2. And there is also a problem that, after reloading the web page, it always shows Hey woman due to `isShowaMale: false` being the default
>    state.

You can think about [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Due to [Why are we disallowed to use HTML5 local storage on code snippets?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345385/why-are-we-disallowed-to-use-html5-local-storage-on-code-snippets)

So you can test the [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-glitter-uy0eg?file=/src/App.js:181-185)

```
constructor() {
 super();
 const isShow = window.localStorage.getItem("data");
 this.state = { isShowMan: isShow === "false" || !isShow ? false : true };
}

toggleShowMan(isShow) {
  window.localStorage.setItem("data", isShow);
  this.setState({ isShowMan: isShow });
}
```

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { isShowMan: true };
  }

  toggleShowMan(isShow) {
    this.setState({ isShowMan: isShow });
  }

  render() {
    const { isShowMan } = this.state;

   return (
      <div className="container py-5">
        <div className="row">
          <button
            disabled={isShowMan}
            className="btn col-6 bg-transparent col-12 col-sm-6"
            onClick={() => this.toggleShowMan(true)}
          >
            malebody{" "}
          </button>
          <button
            disabled={!isShowMan}
            className="btn col-6 bg-transparent col-12 col-sm-6"
            onClick={() => this.toggleShowMan(false)}
          >
            femalebody
          </button>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          {`Hey ${isShowMan? " man" : "woman"}!`} 
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: In the 2nd part, it only disables the button but doesn't hide the div which is already on display due to `isShowMale` being false.

Comment: @KanchanBharti I've updated my answer, pls take a look at it with [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-glitter-uy0eg?file=/src/App.js:181-185)

Comment: Actually what I am trying to do is that, after reloading no div should be displayed. That means no button is pre selected after a reload. Can we do that?

Comment: It seems to me that it's out of scope this question. You can search more about `componentDidmount` to achieve it.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I got it, I took one state `showdiv` which allowed me to show the div itself.  When any button is clicked, the showdiv is given a true value (I defined that in `toggleShowMale`), and when that's true, it displays the div.

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATE] following further clarification in the comments, the issue can be handles in a way similar to this:

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isShowaMale: false
        };
        this.toggleShowMale = this.toggleShowMale.bind(this);
    }

    toggleShowMale(show) {
        this.setState({ isShowaMale:show });
    }

  render() {
    const formProps = this.state.isShowMale
      ? { title: 'Mr', name: 'John', surname: 'Doe' }
      : { title: 'Ms', name: 'Jane', surname: 'Doe' };

    return (
      <div className="container py-5">
        <div className="row">
          <button className="btn col-6 bg-transparent col-12 col-sm-6" onClick={()=> this.toggleShowMale(true)} >
            <img className="humanbody profile" src={malebody} />
          </button>
          <button className="btn col-6 bg-transparent col-12 col-sm-6" onClick={()=> this.toggleShowMale(false)} >
            <img className="humanbody profile" src={femalebody} alt="" />
          </button>
        </div>


        {/* Hidden div */}
        <div className="row mx-auto">
          <div className="mx-auto">
            <form>
              <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder={formProps.title} />
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder={formProps.title} />
              <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" placeholder={formProps.title} />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* Hidden div */}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Or the entire form can be placed into a separate function (or even a separate component).

---

[ORIGINAL ANSWER]

You simply replace

```js
{/* Hidden div */}
<div className="row mx-auto">
  {isShowaMale && (
  <div className="mx-auto">
    Hey man!
  </div>
  )}
  {!isShowaMale && (
  <div>
    Hey woman!
  </div>
  )}
</div>
{/* Hidden div */}
```

with

```js
{/* Hidden div */}
<div className="row mx-auto">
  <div className="mx-auto">
    Hey {isShowaMale ? 'man' : 'woman'}!
  </div>
</div>
{/* Hidden div */}
```